# acts_as_taggable_on Gem not working for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I made a rails application and added the acts-as-taggable-on gem, ran the rake db:migrate and added the field to Article.rb.  I seem to get this error with a rail 5.1 app.  I can't figure out what it is.

**GemFile**

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 4.0'
```

**Article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    include TheComments::Commentable

     acts_as_taggable_on :tags

        belongs_to :user

      # Denormalization methods
      # Check the documentation for information on advanced usage
        def commentable_title
        title
      end

      def commentable_url
        ['', self.class.to_s.tableize, id].join('/')
      end

      def commentable_state
        :published.to_s
      end
    end
```

However I get this error:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18395
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.2)
2.4.0-rc1 :001 > Article
NoMethodError: undefined method `acts_as_taggable_on' for Article (call 'Article.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from app/models/article.rb:6:in `<class:Article>'
    from app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):1
2.4.0-rc1 :002 > Article
NoMethodError: undefined method `acts_as_taggable_on' for Article (call 'Article.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from app/models/article.rb:6:in `<class:Article>'
    from app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding the gem to the Gemfile? Did you restart the string and the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue is with the version of the gem. The version of the gem that you are using doesn't support Rails 5.

You can resolve your error by pulling the gem from direct from the github.
For that just use below code in your gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', :git => 'https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on'
```

Comment: so I updated the new gem reinstalled the schema, ran rake db:migrate and still get the same error.  It seems that the method still is not recognized.

Comment: When I try to add require the gem I get: LoadError: cannot load such file -- acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: Did you follow all installation techniques as per https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#installation. If yes, please provide detailed error.

Comment: THank you.  Solved

Answer (score 2):

They have version 5 which is not mentioned. The documentation says that version 4 works with both Rails 4 and 5 which is inaccurate. I added the following to my Gemfile and got it working. The GitHub link is my reference point.

```
gem "acts-as-taggable-on", "~> 5.0"
```

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/866